# Python while loop subtraction

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is a really stupid question but I haven't used this in awhile and can't remember how to do it. I'm doing a recursion problem and need to show the numbers counting down to basically show how the recursion is working. However, I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code.

```
def main():

    #have user input first number
    x = int(input('Enter the first number: '))

    #have user input second number
    y = int(input('Enter the second number: '))

    #calculate result by calling recursive function
    result = mult(x, y)

    #print the result
    print(x, 'times', y, 'is', result)

#define a function that uses recursion
def mult(x, y):
    # create a loop to display the numbers
    count = y
    while count > 0:
        print('First number =', x, 'Second number =', count)
        count -= 1
    #use recursion to multiply the numbers
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    elif x == 1:
        return y
    else:
        return y + mult(x - 1, y)

main()
```

I need the output to say this:

```
Enter the first number: 5
Enter the second number: 7
First number = 5 Second Number = 7
First number = 5 Second Number = 6
First number = 5 Second Number = 5
First number = 5 Second Number = 4
First number = 5 Second Number = 3
First number = 5 Second Number = 2
First number = 5 Second Number = 1
5 times 7 = 35
```

So it's working for the most part, however now it is displaying this:

```
Enter the first number: 5
Enter the second number: 7
First number = 5 Second number = 7
First number = 5 Second number = 6
First number = 5 Second number = 5
First number = 5 Second number = 4
First number = 5 Second number = 3
First number = 5 Second number = 2
First number = 5 Second number = 1
First number = 4 Second number = 7
First number = 4 Second number = 6
First number = 4 Second number = 5
First number = 4 Second number = 4
First number = 4 Second number = 3
First number = 4 Second number = 2
First number = 4 Second number = 1
First number = 3 Second number = 7
First number = 3 Second number = 6
First number = 3 Second number = 5
First number = 3 Second number = 4
First number = 3 Second number = 3
First number = 3 Second number = 2
First number = 3 Second number = 1
First number = 2 Second number = 7
First number = 2 Second number = 6
First number = 2 Second number = 5
First number = 2 Second number = 4
First number = 2 Second number = 3
First number = 2 Second number = 2
First number = 2 Second number = 1
First number = 1 Second number = 7
First number = 1 Second number = 6
First number = 1 Second number = 5
First number = 1 Second number = 4
First number = 1 Second number = 3
First number = 1 Second number = 2
First number = 1 Second number = 1
5 times 7 is 35
```

Comment: Please also describe what the output is *instead*.

Comment: Move the `print` statements to be inside the `mult` function, above the if statement.

Comment: The output i am getting is an infinite loop of this First number = 5 Second Number = 6. It's not even outputting the second number as 7 first and doesn't go below 6

Comment: Your `while` loop has nothing to do with your recursion and could not possibly show the recursive function's progress. You need to print your diagnostic information inside the recursive function, not in an external loop.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. Yeah, someone else said that too. I understand it now!

Answer (score 2):

The point of printing the two numbers is to keep track of the recursion. So naturally, the numbers must be printed from *inside* the recursing function. In other words, you don't want to *create an additional loop* (using `while`) to display the numbers, but the recursion *is* the loop.

You also only want to print the numbers *once* per recursion step.

What may have additionally confused you is that you have swapped the roles of "first"/`x` and "second"/`y` between the desired output and the argument order of the recursion. (You want the "second" number to decrease in the output, but you decrease the *first* argument (`x`) of `mult`.)

It should look like this:

```
def mult(x, y):
    """Calculate x * y by using recursion."""
    print('First number =', x, 'Second number =', y)
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    elif y == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return x + mult(x, y - 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    y = int(input('Enter the second number: '))

    # calculate result by calling recursive function
    result = mult(x, y)

    # print the result
    print(x, 'times', y, 'is', result)
```

Comment: Oh you're right. I remember reading that now. You either use a loop or recursion, not both right?

Comment: @Classicalclown Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you aren't storing your modified `y` value.  So, the while loop should read like this:

```
y_temp = y
while y_temp > 0:
    print('First number =', x, 'Second number =', y_temp)
    y_temp -= 1
```

Comment: This is working, however, now my total is incorrect since it thinks y = 0 now instead of 7 so my end output is 5 times 0 = 0 instead of 5 times 7 = 35

Comment: Store the first value of `y` in another variable and use that in your last print

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I appreciate it

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change you need to make, you need to update the value of `y` in the `while loop`.

```
#create a loop to display the numbers
while y > 0:
    print('First number =', x, 'Second number =', y)
    y -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is outside the recursive call, so the value of `y` is not getting updated. Move the `print` statements to be inside the `mult` function, above the `if` statement.

```
def mult(x, y):
    print('First number =', x, 'Second number =', y)
    print('First number =', x, 'Second number =', y - 1)
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    elif x == 1:
        return y
    else:
        return y + mult(x - 1, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to update `y`, you're not decreasing `y`.